# how to submit a form through anchor tag such that radio button is also selected?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

```
<script language="javascript">

function customFunction(url){

alert(url);

//window.location = "url";

//document.all.url.checked = true;

document.getElementById('url').checked = true;

document.downloadable_prod.submit();
}
</script>

<!-- Note : this below radio buttons coming from loop --->

<input type="radio" name="links" id="links_<?php echo $_link->getId() ?>" value="<?php echo $_link->getId() ?>" />

<a href="javascript:customFunction(<?php echo $_link->getId() ?>);" class="buy_stan">

<span style="margin-left:160px;">

   <?php echo $this->getFormattedLinkPrice($_link); ?>
```

Comment: if it doesn't make sense or it is not enough to make sense then ask me questions or i will provide the whole code

Comment: there will be two or more radio button, hope u can get this by reading note and also by looking at id of radio button field

Comment: Its better to write more in the body of your question ratehr than trying to fit it into the title and then povide the code.Coudl you explain what you trying to do. Do you want to click the anchor and make it select the radio button before submitting the form?

Comment: yes exactly :) u got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your radio buttons have a link of "links_xxxx", xxx being whatever your php is returning. in your anchor tag you need to add links to the custom function call. Try the below

Note I added 'links_ after customFunction( and closed it off using ' at the end of your php call.

```
<a href="javascript:customFunction('links_<?php echo $_link->getId() ?>');" class="buy_stan">
```

Comment: don know wat was the error but i replace the code with original code and apply the same function on it , it started working fine :)